# Grails - how to display result page at a unique URL

Tags: grails

I have a grails application that takes user input (create page/method), the user then clicks a Save button (save method that executes service) and then the results are displayed (list method) on a page, for example http://localhost:8080/myApp/myclass/save.

The users would like each results run to be saved to a unique URL so they can share it, bookmark it, save it later, whatever. I have NO idea how to go about this and google searches turn up little to nothing.

For example an application run would result in the data being displayed at http://localhost:8080/myApp/myclass/systemname/datetimestring/someuniquedata/

Is this even possible? Any pointers GREATLY appreciated.

*EDIT*

Here is my urlMappings contents.

```
 class UrlMappings {

     static mappings = {
         "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
             constraints {
                 // apply constraints here
             }
     }

         "/" {
             controller = "api"
             action = "create"
         }

         "500"(view:'/error')
    }
 }
```

When I display the results it's done through the list method shown here.

```
def list(Integer max) {
    List<Api> api = Api.findAllBySessionId(session.id, [sort:'dateCreated'])
    api = api[-2..-1]
    [apiInstanceList: api, apiInstanceTotal: api.size()]
}
```

So I have the unique session ID. How do I need to modify "mappings"?

Answer (score 0):

Every domain object that you're saving will have an autogenerated ID (assuming you're using GORM, which is definitely likely).  It sounds like all you're asking for is a /show/id page where you can access a particular object via ID.

A url mapping for `"/$controller/$action?/$id?"` is a pretty straightfoward way to handle this, and is provided by default (and used by scaffolded controllers also).

If you'd rather not use an autogenerated ID (maybe you're moving objects from one database to another, or updating the ID for some reason?) you can consider using `java.util.UUID.randomUUID()` to generate a random, unique identifier and save that as a field on your object.  You could then use .findByUuid with the input parameter.

Comment: Yes, I'm generating and using a session id for concurrent use of the application! That will work. I'll dig into this tomorrow and if I have any questions I'll follow up here. Thank you!

Comment: Your edit relies on session ID, which is going to change from session to session (timing based on how long your sessions last) and is not repeatable from one user to another.  I don't imagine that's what you want.